# Android scrollview as listitem

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a listview that has custom child items. Each list item has scrollview inside. Its not good practice to put scrollview inside listview but my requirement is like that.

Example:  I have a listview and date picker kind of view has child element. Now how do I scroll the child views in each list item?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `ScrollView` as a row item within a `ListView` try using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)